# How do i skip the index file and directly show the json response?

Tags: java, jsp, jersey-2.0

I have developed the `Rest API` in `Java` using `Jersey 2.6`, server is `Apache Tomcat` and getting response in `JSON`. when i run the project by right click and click on `run on server` option one `html` page is showed up i.e. `index.html`

[image]

Below is my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.xyz.webservices</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Code for `index.jsp` file

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
    <p><a href="webapi/getConfigFiles">Jersey resource</a>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my resource file that i am calling after click that button "Jersey Resource"

```
package com.xyz.webservices;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Path("getConfigFiles")
public class Resource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getConfigFiles() 
    {
        Response response = null;
        try {
        List<String> listConfig = new ArrayList<>();

        String ROOT_FILE_PATH="E:\\eSamridhi\\Data\\ConfigData";
        File f=new File(ROOT_FILE_PATH);
        File[] allSubFiles=f.listFiles();

        for (File file : allSubFiles) 
        {
            listConfig.add(file.getName().replace(".xlsx", ""));
        }

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("ConfigFiles", listConfig);  
        System.out.println(object);
        response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(object.toString()).build();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;



    }
}
```

this is my response after clicking the button

[image]

So my question is instead of showing index file first directly show the response `JSON` after visiting the `URL`.How do i redirect or direct remove the in between step so i can directly get the response i am beginner hence not getting.
Any help will be appreciated.
Because after this i am developing the front end where i need to directly show the data by calling above API.

Thank you for you consideration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a number of different ways. For example you could have javascript on your html page that would do a button click on page load. Another better way of doing this is to create a new servlet and map your welcome-file-list in web.xml to this servlet. For example, make a servlet called 'Test' with url mapping /Test.

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
         see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Test</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.xyz.webservices</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Now when you application first loads, the doGet method in the servlet Test will be called. From here we can call your Resource class

```
@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Test() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      //here you should be able to call this method
      Resource r = new Resource();
      r.getConfigFiles();  


     }

}
```